# Why @mixin don't compiles to @media in css

Tags: css, sass

please tell me why this sass code does not compile to css. Mixin seems to be ignored. Could there be a problem with the incorrect variable declaration?

```
@mixin superVar($var, $number, $vh, $vw) {
  @media (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
    $var: $number * $vh;
  }
  @media (max-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
    $var: $number * $vw;
  }
}
.frame {
  @include superVar(--superVmin, 1, 2vh, 1vw);
  width: calc(10 * var(--superVmin));
  height: 10vmin;
  background: red;
}

//compiles to 
.frame {
  width: calc(10 * var(--superVmin));
  height: 10vmin;
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[As noted on the Sass website](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars):

> To provide maximum compatibility with plain CSS, more recent versions of Sass require SassScript expressions in custom property values to be written within interpolation. Interpolation will also work for older Sass versions, and so is recommended for all stylesheets.

In the site's example, they interpolate the value of the variable. In your particular case, though, it seems we need to interpolate the variable name itself instead.

```
@mixin superVar($var, $number, $vh, $vw) {
  @media (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
    #{$var}: $number * $vh;
  }
  @media (max-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
    #{$var}: $number * $vw;
  }
}
.frame {
  @include superVar(--superVmin, 1, 2vh, 1vw);
  width: calc(10 * var(--superVmin));
  height: 10vmin;
  background: red;
}
```

Outputs:

```
.frame {
  width: calc(10 * var(--superVmin));
  height: 10vmin;
  background: red;
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
  .frame {
    --superVmin: 2vh;
  }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
  .frame {
    --superVmin: 1vw;
  }
}
```